# MYSQL : give permissions to all users for a database

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, mysql-error-1064

I need to give permissions to all users for a database,

I m trying to do this using following statement:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON `kdb`.* TO ' '@'%';
```

but it gives me error:

```
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Can anyone tell me how can I give permission to all available users to a particular database, so that every time a new user is created it get access to the that database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

This user is a "Super User" and it can be connected from any host to MySQL server you can specify a specific IP instead of `%`

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE(TEMPORARY) ON `kdb`.* TO ''@'%';
```

I think this will resolve your problem

Comment: GRANT ALL ON kdb.* TO ''@'%';